# How to install babel cli ni a project in windows os properly

Tags: windows, npm, babeljs

I already have package.json file and try to install babel using this command

```
npm install babel-cli@6.18.0 --save-dev
```

but I got this error

```
npm WARN react-essential@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\eujso\Desktop\Ex_Files_React_EssT_Upd\Exercise Files\Ch02\02_01\start\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-7a36a307\node_modules\wrappy' -> 'C:\Users\eujso\Desktop\Ex_Files_React_EssT_Upd\Exercise Files\Ch02\02_01\start\node_modules\.staging\wrappy-de23cf94'

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\eujso\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-27T09_35_24_484Z-debug.log
```

I don't know what to do with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my malwarebytes is the reason, other people have problem installing with npm because of their anti-virus, this commonly happen in window os